# Making non editable pdf using ItextRender

Tags: java, spring-boot, pdf-generation, itextrenderer

I am trying to generate a pdf from HTML page. For this I am using ITextRenderer. In my html code having multiple check boxes. I have disabled those check boxes. But when I convert HTML to pdf , PDF is generated. When I opened it on browser, all the check box fields are editable. How can I made a PDF non editable. Below is my code.[image: code snippet image]